# Installing FFmpeg in Red Hat 5 without internet connection

Tags: ffmpeg, redhat

I am trying to install the last working version of FFmpeg over Red Hat 5 and the machine has no internet connection, so I have to bring all the packages and required dependencies in a USB. The problem I am having is to get everything I would need for it.

I searched through Google to find some guide or documentation to hep me, but there is nothing valuable for me.

The version I got install was FFmpeg 0.6, but it is too old for my purpose of grabbing with x11grab, so anyone has any suggestion in order to get install one of the last versions of FFmpeg.

Comment: Have you tried FFmpeg static builds [here](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)?

Comment: @Timothy_G Those don't have x11grab support.

Comment: At a minimum you'll probably need the following packages and whatever dependencies they require: `gcc` `make` `libX11-devel` `libXext-devel` `libXfixes-devel` `pkgconfig` `zlib-devel`. You'll also need the source code for Yasm, x264, and FFmpeg.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Many thanks for the answers. I hope I could prove it tomorrow, I don't always have access to it, so I just can work on it once or twice per week.

Comment: @Timothy_G the x11grab is essential, because my project is to record two monitors on a machine running RedHat. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proxy access configure yum to use that proxy server, this can be easily achieved with yum config file “/etc/yum.conf“. Under main section define the proxy settings like below:

```
[main]
………………
proxy=http://<Proxy-Server-IP-Address>:<Proxy_Port>
proxy_username=<Proxy-User-Name>
proxy_password=<Proxy-Password> 
………………
```

If not you can use a second server (maybe your laptop) with the same version of RHEL and download the main rpm and the dependencies.

```
# yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <main_package>
```

Make sure to create a directory first and put it in downloaddir, the main rpm file could have many many dependencies but all are going to be stored in < directory >.  After that install first the dependencies and at the end the main rpm file.

```
# for i in $(ls -1 downloaddir/*.rpm); do yum localinstall downloaddir/$i -y; done
# yum localinstall <main_package>
```